# Xamarin.Forms - KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms and I getting this error:

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary

For this line:

```
bool isLogin = (bool)Application.Current.Properties["isLogin"];
```

I tried to check to see if the key existed like so:

```
if(Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("isLogin"))
            {
                bool isLogin = (bool)Application.Current.Properties["isLogin"];

                string username = Application.Current.Properties["username"].ToString();

                if (isLogin)
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage(), true);
                }
            }
```

But checking the key always returns false even after setting the key and value:

```
Application.Current.Properties["isLogin"] = true;
```

Comment: When do you set the value in the dictionary? Perhaps you set it AFTER checking for it. Please give a little more context.

Comment: I would set it after a successful login, when I run the app again, it says its doesnt exists

Comment: Well of course, that dictionary is stored in memory, so it's destroyed and reinitialized upon application restart. Therefore you should either persist the login data locally (file, sqlite, etc.) and initialize it from the locally stored data at app startup, or re-initialize the app WITHOUT restarting it, after login.

Comment: You are trying to get the key before adding it simple!

Comment: Oh I thought Application.Current.Properties would work when restarting the application

Comment: Adding this code after setting the values appears to work: await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();

Comment: Is it possible that `Application.Current.Properties["username"]` is the code throwing the exception?

Comment: From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#persistence), The Properties dictionary is saved to the device automatically. Data added to the dictionary will be available when the application returns from the background or even after it is restarted. Your code for isLogin works well on my side. Always set the value before use it.

Answer (score 0):

Application.Current.Properties will be exists even if you kill the application and restart it again. Just try in this way unplug your device and try to login and check, it will work. While debugging it won't work.